# SQL NOT LIKE - Not working

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

**UPDATE 2:**

In one of the rows, in the column `closed_by`, it contains a `null`.  If I replace the null with text, the query starts working, but it will not work with `null`.  So it seems `null` is the problem, but the query should return rows which have `null` too, as `pqr` does not equal `null`.

**UPDATE 1:**

I have also tried `set     @user = 'pqr'`, but it makes no difference.  It still returns 0 rows, when it should be returning 1 row, as 1 of the rows does not contain `pqr`.

**ORIGINAL QUESTION:**

I am trying to return rows which do not contain the id provided:

```
declare @user varchar(3)
set     @user = 'pqr'

select * from table1 where not( closed_by like @user )
```

closed_by contains data like

```
abc,def,ghi,jkl,mno
```

But this gives me no errors and returns no data, it should be returning a single row as `pqr` is not in 1 row.

Not sure what I am doing wrong.

Comment: In which row `pnr` is not there???
as per your example 'pnr' is no where

Comment: when you added the wildcard characters, did you set the size of @user to 5 instead of 3?

Comment: Note for UPDATE 2: Check answers below, and other references, for how NULL logic works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include a wildcard character:

```
declare 
@user varchar(5) 
set @user = '%pqr%'  

select * 
from table1 
where isnull(closed_by, '') not like @user
```

Answer (score 3):

You may want to check the [syntax of the `LIKE` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx) - it accetps a **pattern** and so you would need to use something like this instead:

```
declare @user varchar(5)
set @user = '%pqr%'
```

The '%' is a wildcard and matches any string of zeor or more chracters.

FYI - SQL Server won't be able to use indexes with a a LIKE pattern that starts with a wildcard and so you may find that your query performs badly with large data sets.

Comment: I have tried that many times, but it makes no difference for some reason.

Comment: @oshirowanen Did you remember to change the size of `@user` to 5? If your variable was still 3 characters in length then you would have just been using `%pq`, which also wouldn't have worked.

Answer (score 2):

`NULL` is unknown and therefore it is unknown whether it is like your pattern or not. You can solve this easily by using:

```
DECLARE @user VARCHAR(5) = '%pqr%';    
SELECT ... WHERE COALESCE(closed_by, '') NOT LIKE @user;
```

And in fact to be more accurate you probably want:

```
DECLARE @user VARCHAR(7) = '%,pqr,%';    
SELECT ... WHERE COALESCE(',' + closed_by + ',', '') NOT LIKE @user;
```

This way, if you later have data like `'trv,pqrs,ltt'` it won't return a false positive.

However, having said all of that, having you considered storing this in a more normalized fashion? Storing comma-separated lists can be very problematic and I can assue you this won't be the last challenge you face with dealing with data structured this way.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `%` and `_` wildcard characters when using LIKE. Without them you actually just have `WHERE NOT (closed_by = @user)`.

Also, be careful of accidental matches.  For example `LIKE '%a%'` would match your example record.  For such cases, I tend to ensure that the comma delimitered lists also have commas at the start and end.  Such as; `',abc,def,ghi,jkl,mno,' LIKE '%,ghi,%'`

But, more over, you're using a relational database.  You would be better off with each entry as it's own record in a normalised structure.  Although this give 1:many relationships, rather than 1:1 relationships, you get the benefits of INDEXes and much more flexibility in your queries.  (Your LIKE example can't use an index.)

**REPLY TO UPDATE 2:**

Be careful of how you assume NULL logic works.

- The result of `NULL LIKE '%pqr%'` is NULL
- The result of `NOT (NULL)` is NULL

You need to change your code to use `WHERE NOT (ISNULL(closed_by, '') LIKE '%pqr%')`

Comment: ? is not a wildcard in SQL Server - you must be thinking of Access or another platform. In SQL Server it is % and _ ...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select * from table1 where closed_by not like @user
```

And you may need to add the appropriate '%' characters to tell SQL Server which portion of the value to search. For example 'pqr%'

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me that you really are looking for equivalence, and not wildcard matches.  Try this:

```
select * from table1 where closed_by <> @user
```